# How to increase the space between my posts?

Tags: image, space, blogger

I don't know anything about HTML codes and I'm using the 'Galauness Blogger Theme' I found on the internet. I changed some things that weren't too hard and the only thing I currently don't like about my blog is the fact that it seems like the wrong title belongs to the wrong blogpost.

If you visit my website it looks like the second row of text belongs to the first row of images but that isn't the case.

Would anyone mind helping me with a) decreasing the space between the text and the image or b) increasing the first row of images and the second row of text?

My website is www.lemontierres.com

Thank you in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is meant for help with practical, programming related questions ([Help/on-topic]), not to solicit "free help" with anything related to computers in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decreasing the space between headline and image is possible, but can get complicated. The reason is each headline in your CSS has a height set to 40px and a padding of 10px. You'll find this in the css for the selector `.post h3`. If the height:40px; would be removed, it looks better as currently all your headlines only have one line, but in case of a single headline with 2 lines the three entries in each row wouldn't be aligned anymore - the fixed height takes care about keeping everything aligned.
To have more space between the entries, you can add padding for a wrapper element - e.g. every entry is wrapped in a div with the classes `post` and `hentry`, so adding

```
.post.hentry {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

will add more space between each row.
I've noticed that adding padding to the outermost wrapper - the div with the class `date-outer` - leads to weird results, but adding it to `.post.hentry` seems to work.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I was able to change it thanks to the comment about the height:40px, I changed that to 20px and it looks fine now! Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sjoukje Glad that I was able to help you. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed/solved. As I noticed you're new to Stackoverflow and maybe don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235